# thank <....>for recommending to+<verb>

Tags: sentence-construction

My technical paper is reviewed by two reviewers. The comment of first review is as follows:

> Reviewer #1: After the first revision, the paper has shown a
>   comprehensive detailed information related to development in renewable
>   energy. I would recommend this paper to be published in the Journal of
>   ClP.

Now I want to thank this reviewer. Is use of "to publish" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> We thank the honorable reviewer for **recommending to publish** the paper
>   and confirming the responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote "my technical paper". If you were the sole author, **we** would be grandiloquent.  **Honorable** is in much the same grand register, but in some countries academics expect to be addressed like grandees, so I won't attempt to dissuade you from using the adjective.

You thank the reviewer for recommending **publication of the paper**.

You thank the reviewer for recommending **that the paper be published**.

You thank the reviewer for recommending **the paper for publication**.

Recommending + {infinitive} is marginally idiomatic in modern English.

P.S. My ear tells me that the third option there is the most suitable choice.